# Raster calculator ERROR000732, python scripter

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000732

I'm trying to do the raster calculator with this script but something goes wrong. It seems that the program doesn't found the files, but they exist. I've tried to remove path from the variables (raster1, raster2 etc) but it is the same.

[image]

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\raster_calc\input"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
raster1 = "C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\raster_calc\input\lito2016_area_studio_cross_curv.img"
raster2 = "C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\raster_calc\input\lito2016_area_studio_flowacc.img"
raster3 = "C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\raster_calc\input\lito2016_area_studio_long_curv.img"
outRas = Raster("raster1") * Raster("raster3")
outRas.save("C:\Users\Elisa\Model_Builder\raster_calc")
```

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 3):

The path slashes are being interpreted as escape characters, use one of the following path slash formats instead:

```
raster1 = "C:/Users/Elisa/... 
raster1 = r"C:\Users\Elisa\... 
raster1 = "C:\\Users\\Elisa\\...
```

Comment: i've tried to do it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you reeving the same or different error?

Comment: The same. I've tried another function in map algebra and it is ok. The problem is in the variable recall but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @ElisaMammoliti remove the quotes in line `outRas = Raster("raster1") * Raster("raster3")`